# What's the difference between findall() and using a for loop with an iterator to find pattern matches

Tags: python, regex

I'm using this to calculate the number of sentences in a text:

```
fileObj = codecs.open( "someText.txt", "r", "utf-8" )
shortText = fileObj.read()

pat = '[.]'

for match in re.finditer(pat, shortText, re.UNICODE):
    nSentences = nSentences+1
```

Someone told me this is better:

```
result = re.findall(pat, shortText)
nSentences = len(result)
```

Is there a difference? Don't they do the same thing?

Comment: you could also do: shortText = "".join(open("someText.txt").readlines() ); nSent = len(shortText.split("."))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second is probably going to be a little faster, since the iteration is done entirely in C. How much faster? About 15% in my tests (matching `'a'` in `'a' * 16`), though that percentage will get smaller as the regex gets more complex and takes a larger proportion of the running time. But it will use more memory since it's actually going to create a list for you. Assuming you don't have a ton of matches, though, not *too* much more memory.

As to which I'd prefer, I do kind of like the second's conciseness, especially when combined into a single statement:

```
nSentences = len(re.findall(pat, shortText))
```

Comment: How did you know that `the iterations are done in C`.? Can you please point me to the current documentation for that.

Comment: Looked at the `re` module's source code, saw that the core implementation is in a module called `_sre`. Printing `sys.modules["_sre"]` reveals this to be built into the Python interpreter and so written in C. `findall` is a "built-in" (i.e., C) method of a pattern object returned by `_sre.compile()`. For other Python implementations, this may differ.

Answer (score 2):

The *finditer* function returns an **iterator** of **match objects**.

The *findall* function returns a **list** of matching **strings**.

The advantage of iterators over lists is that they are memory friendly (producing values only when needed).

The advantage of match objects over strings is that they are versatile (giving you groups, groupdict, start, end, span, etc.).

The choice of which is best depends on your needs.  If you need a list of matching strings, then *findall* is great.  If you need match object methods or if you need to conserve memory, then *finditer* is the way to go.

Hope this helps. Good luck with your project :-)

Answer (score 1):

They do much the same thing. Your choice should be dictated by whether your other usage suggests an iterator or list would be better.

Comment: They both do the same loop, right? findall() is like a wrapper of the first loop?

Answer (score 1):

One difference between `finditer` and `findall` is that the former returns regex `match objects` whereas the other return a list of groups if one or more groups are present in the pattern; this will be a `list of tuples` if the pattern has more than one group.

Other than that it all depends on your usage.

Comment: so the difference is mainly the return value. They both do the same loop, right?

Answer (score 1):

There are two main differences:

1) `findall()` returns a list, while `finditer()` returns a iterator. This could be a huge difference if you're going to handle big strings (like files).

2) `findall()` returns `str` objects, while `finditer()` returns `Match` objects. I think that's the major difference. So, depending of what information you need from the matches, you can choose between one or the other. Here a small example:

We want to get all the numbers from a string:

```
>>> s = 'I have 921 apples, 53 oranges, 3 bananas and 1 lemon.'
# if you just need to find them, better use findall():
>>> re.findall('\d+', s)
['921', '53', '3', '1']
# but, if you need more than just that, use finditer():
>>> [(m.group(), m.start(), m.end()) for m in re.finditer('\d+', s)]
[('921', 7, 10), ('53', 19, 21), ('3', 31, 32), ('1', 45, 46)]
```